# Excel data validation depending on other column value

Tags: excel

I have to create an excel spreadsheet having three columns Country, City and Region. The columns need to have a drop-down list to validate the data.

Master List:

```
Country      City          Region
England      London        Central
England      London        West
England      London        East
England      Manchester
Switzerland  Zurich
Switzerland  Basel         North
Switzerland  Basel         West
```

I can create a drop-down for Country and City using "Data Validation" > "Allow" > "List". However, how can I validate the selected area belongs to the selected city / country for the given row? In fact, if possible, I would like to show only selected country's cities and selected city's regions in the drop-down.

Example:

```
Country    City     Region    Valid
England    London   Central   Yes
England    Basel    Central   No
```

Comment: https://exceljet.net/dependent-dropdown-lists - "a list of cities that depends on the selected country" is even mentioned as an example of a dependent dropdown :)

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, it will work with two columns. However, I just realized I have three columns hierarchy. I have updated the question with three columns.